# Is it possible to create bindings to javafx.beans.property.ListProperty properties in fxml?

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I am trying to separate all relations between ui-elements (i.e. "disable button if textfield is empty") to fxml.
This works fine in most cases, but it seems to be impossible to bind to *java.util.List* derived classes.
It always ends in *java.lang.NumberFormatException* caused by *com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.get()*:

```java
public static <T> T get(Object namespace, String key) {

...
    if (namespace instanceof List<?>) {
        List<Object> list = (List<Object>)namespace;
        **value = list.get(Integer.parseInt(key));**
    }
...
```

where key is the property-name I try to bind to (i.e. "empty" if binding to "myListProperty.empty").
FXMLLoader tries to get the value at index "property-name" instead of getting the according property (as it does correctly if the namespace-object does not implement *java.util.List*).

The attached short example shows how to reproduce the behavior:

**Main-class**

```
package test.fxml;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root  = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource( "./Test.fxml" ) );
        Scene  scene = new Scene( root,300,250 );

        primaryStage.setTitle( "Test App" );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Application.launch( args );
    }
}
```

**Controller-class (empty)**

```
package test.fxml;

public class Controller
{
    public Controller()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

**FXML-file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.92"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="test.fxml.Controller">

    <fx:define>
      <SimpleListProperty fx:id="myListProperty" />
    </fx:define>

    <TextField fx:id="myTextField"
               text="does not work"
               disable="${myListProperty.empty}"/>

</VBox>
```

**Excerpt from the stack-trace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "empty"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.get(Expression.java:623)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.get(Expression.java:597)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.get(Expression.java:597)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.get(Expression.java:576)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.VariableExpression.evaluate(VariableExpression.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.ExpressionValue.getValue(ExpressionValue.java:192)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:54)
    at javafx.beans.value.ObservableValueBase.addListener(ObservableValueBase.java:55)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.ExpressionValue.addListener(ExpressionValue.java:201)
    at javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding.bind(BooleanBinding.java:107)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$1.<init>(BooleanPropertyBase.java:169)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.bind(BooleanPropertyBase.java:166)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:319)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
```

My questions are:
1. Does anybody know if this is a bug in fxml?
2. If not, can anyone please explain the special handling for *java.util.List* to me?
3. Is it possible to fulfill the requirement "enable/disable ui-components according list-size or list-state **only** by fxml"?

Many thanks in advance for your help.